# How to publish flutter module on jfrog/maven to integrate on existing iOS native app?

Tags: ios, flutter, maven, artifactory, flutter-module

I have created a flutter module which I need to integrate in iOS native.
Followed the  Option-C to generated pod 'Flutter.podspec' using below reference.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

It generated three folder build, profile, release and based on requirement I successfully integrated it manually.
But I want to publish this pod folder on **jfrog/maven** so that any client or user can simply fetch it and integrate OR some other way to upload flutter module on jfrog/maven. Somehow I need to use this repository only.

Answer (score 0):

in order to add your flutter module into existing native app, you can use the plugin namely : [Cocoapods-embed-flutter](https://github.com/DartBuild/cocoapods-embed-flutter). So, you don't have to deploy your podspecs into jfrog or anything. Just add that plugin in your project, and pod install. For more details, check the documentation for this plugin.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31977681)